# List View item progress is not updating

Tags: android, android-listview, android-layout-weight

I am using a list view to show multiple pdf files.

Each item contains a button on clicking which that item progress bar gets visible and shows progress (working fine). I have also given an option to download all items by giving a button on clicking with all item progress should be visible and should show the progress each item.

But as my list view only displays two items on a screen at a time I don't have convert view object of other items to get the progress bar and update them, only those two item progress bar is shown and gets updated. when user scrolls the list he see an empty progress on each item because I don't have the convert view object to get the progress bar of that item.

How can I get all the convert view objects while rendering the list view. I will store all these objects in a list and when user will scroll the list i will update the corresponding item progress bar. Or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep all the convertView because of recycling.
For example your first view will be reused somewhere in your list when you scroll it (maybe in 4th position, who knows, depends how many are visible on screen)

Your downloading status should be a part of your data bean not of your view.
Each time your getView function is called in your adapter you should "plug" the correct info and listeners into your progressbar (make sure the progress on downloading 1st element won't make the progressbar of the fourth one to move)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should hold progress information about all the list items and use it inside `getView` method of your adapter. Don't forget - you should show progress bar for elements with started download and hide it for elements without download.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the viewholders directly to change the state of your list items.

Instead, add a `boolean loading` attribute to your data class. When you bind the view to your data, check this attribute to show or hide the progress bar.

When you download one or more items in your list, update your underlying data, then call [`myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to refresh the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the data of the progress bar in an array object and in the list adapter you have to assign the relevant value to the relevant item in the list adapter, you can maintain that data in an object array that will contain all the necessary information of each of the list item.